# Hub Docker Total Size

Tags: docker, statistics

Is there a method to determine the size of the Official Hub Docker repository? Such as for the official PyPi repo through https://pypi.org/stats

I tried using a PyPi script (https://pypi.org/project/docker-registry-statistics/) to determine the size but the script won't recognize https://hub.docker.com/_ as a directory.

Thank you for the help.